Dragging an entity around immersive Space in VisionOS
I'm trying to understand how Apple handles dragging windows around in an immersive space. 3d Gestures seem to be only half of the solution in that they are great if you're standing still and want to move the window an exaggerated amount around the environment, but if you then start walking while dragging, the amplified gesture sends the entity flying off into the distance. It seems they quickly transition from one coordinate systems to another depending on if the user is physically moving (the movement suddenly matches the speed of the user). When you stop moving, you can push and pull the windows around again like a super hero. Am I missing something obvious in how to copy this behavior? Hello world, which uses the 3d gesture has the same problem. You can move the world around but if you walk with it, it flies off. Are they tracking the head movement and if it's moved more than a certain amount it uses that offset instead? Is there anything out of the box that can do this before I try and hack my own solution?
